# Is teleported to body component, declared inside another component available after parent component unmount?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-teleport

I have 2 components which are modal windows, where the second one is declared inside the first one template using a teleport like:

```
<!-- TheFirstComponent -->
<template>
  <Teleport to="body">
    <TheSecondComponent />
  </Teleport>
</template>
```

My question is:
Will be TheSecondComponent available if TheFirstComponent is unmounted (modal window closed) due to teleport usage?

Comment: It shouldn't, It would be a leak otherwise. the point of native teleport/portal feature is that it handles DOM changes according to component structure. If this isn't in your case, you can safely report it as Vue bug.